# PHP code used in website returns network IP of user and not public IP

Tags: php, ip-address

I have PHP code that is supposed to detect a user's IP address. The code below returns an IP address, but the IP address is sometimes a local network IP (e.g. 10.0.0.1) and not a public IP. How can I ensure that I always get the public IP? Thanks. BTW, this code is from another StackOverflow post. Also, this code is used in a website that is being accessed over the internet from a completely separate network than that of my Apache web server.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])){  
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];  
} elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){  
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];  
} elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"])){  
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];  
} elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"])){  
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];  
} elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"])){  
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];  
} else {   
  $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];  
}
```

Comment: @TJHeuvel  No, this happens with actual users.  I know that one particular user was accessing the US based website from Europe using Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate all the `if(){} else{}` code, and just request the `REMOTE_ADDR`:

```
 $ip =  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

It's the only reliable source of a user's remote IP address as all the other `_SERVER` keys can be masked by the client.

If the IP address is still local (and youre SURE that you're dealing with clients not in the networks or on a local VPN) the you may be dealing with either a server caching system (Squid Proxy eg). Have a look at http://www.nineteenlabs.com/2007/08/24/high-anonymous-proxy-squid-25/